# Max two MediaElements show

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to display multiple MediaElements in a ListBox:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <MediaElement Height="200" Source="source.mp4" AutoPlay="False" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <MediaElement Height="200" Source="source.mp4" AutoPlay="False" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <MediaElement Height="200" Source="source.mp4" AutoPlay="False" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

The problem is only two of them show... Why is that?
I know there can only play one at a time, thats not a problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are accessing the same source file multiple times. It should not be a problem to let many mediaelements play at the same time except from your pcs resources. Ensure that you add distinct instances of ME.

Comment: The same source file is just for example. In my app, the ListBox gets created dynamically and the source is different.

Comment: I think, actually, only the playing one should be shown. For some reason if all of them are set to autoplay, 2 are shown, but that's not the expected behavior. Because if you have a single MediaElement and it's not set to autoplay nothing will be shown until it starts playing.
I would populate the list with thumbnails from the videos.